# Error in PDO page Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

I am very new to PDO.

I tried making a login page to my website and the code is shown below

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['username'])and isset($_POST['password']))
     { 

session_start();
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hydra', 'root', '');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM login where username=:username AND password=:password");
    $query->bindValue(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();

    if($query->rowcount() >0 )
    {
        echo "No Records Found!";
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        header("Location: home.php");

    }




           }
         ?>
```

after trying to login, I got this following error :
 **Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object**

Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
    $stmt->bindValue(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
```

You have to create a statement (`$stmt`) via `$db->prepare("sql")` not a query. Then you can bind params to the prepared statement and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use prepare() not query()

Your code also is too bloated.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login where username=? AND password=?");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['username'], $_POST['password']]);
```

is enough
Also, you have to add this line after connect

```
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Answer (score 0):

`PDO::query` return Values are `PDOStatement` object or `FALSE` on failure.

In your case a failure occurred and the returned value is `FALSE` instead of being a `PDOStatement` object.

Use `var_dump` right after `$query = $db->query(...` to make sure you are receiving an error. And use PDO error checking to find out what the error message is.

Answer (score 0):

try use prepare() method instead of query()

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login where username=:username AND password=:password");

$query->bindValue(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```